# Calculating weight ratios in the presence of empty cells

Tags: r

I have a sample which needs to weighed in order to represent the population.

```
library(data.table)
sample <- fread("
1,0,2,2
3,4,3,0
")

   V1 V2 V3 V4
1:  1  0  2  2
2:  3  4  3  0

population <- fread("
10,20,20,10
30,40,20,10
")
```

This weight would simply be:

```
weights <- population/sample

   V1  V2        V3 V4
1: 10 Inf 10.000000  5
2: 10  10  6.666667 Inf
```

However, because `V2` in `row 1` of the sample has no observations, it receives an infinite weight (Note that also `V4` in `row 2` receives an `Inf`, but this is easier to solve, because the weight is irrelevant, as there are no observations in either the sample or the population).

A solution to the problem, would be to count `V1` and `V2` together in the sample and the population.

## EDIT:

After some thought I realised that, for the weights to be correct, only the population values have to be adapted. If `V1` and `V2` in `row 1` of `population` are added together in `V1` of `population`, this will already lead to the correct weight for the sample observation of `V1 row` . The value of V2 becomes irrelevant because there is no observation in the sample to receive that weight.

## End of EDIT

The observation would then get a weight of:

```
(population[1,1]+population[1,2])/(sample[1,1]+sample[1,2])

(10+20)/(1+0)=30
```

In my actual data, there however many more rows, with hero and there a `0` in the sample. I am trying to figure out if there is a way to write my code, so that I do not have to do this manually..

Desired outcome (notice that the weight of `V1` `row 1` is now `30`):

> weights

```
   V1  V2        V3 V4
1: 30   0 10.000000  5
2: 10  10  6.666667  0
```

## Attempt

I was think of doing something like:

```
for (i in seq_along(ncol(sample))) {
 lapply(population, (ifelse(sample[i]==0), population[i]<-population[i+1], population[i])
}
```

Where the values in the population of the cell to right will be added when the value in the sample is zero. However I am having trouble getting the syntax right, and even if it did, it does not solve the case where `V4` is `0`.

Comment: Why yould you just apply the logic of adding V1 and V2? Why not V3 and V4 as well? Would you accept a solution that aggregates V1 and V2 in population where either is 0 in sample?

Comment: @mnist I if I understand you correctly , that is fine. If the population is `0`, the sample has to be `0`. In essence, only the population values have to be adapted, conditional on the sample value being zero.

Comment: @mnist In other words, the weights of `V4` in `row 2` are irrelevant, because they will not be attached to any observation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rather verbose solution. In case there are more columns that should be aggregated in case of zeros in sample, I would have proposed a more flexible approach but this seems sufficient for your example

```
  library(data.table)
  sample <- fread("
1,0,2,2
3,4,3,0
")
  
  population <- fread("
10,20,20,10
30,40,20,10
")
  
  
  # aggregate Values if sample is zero
  population[sample$V1 == 0, `:=`(V1 = 0,
                                  V2 = V1 + V2)]
  population[sample$V2 == 0, `:=`(V1 = V1 + V2,
                                  V2 = 0)]
  
  weights <- population/sample
  # Fix NaNs
  weights[is.na(weights), ] <- 0
  weights
#>    V1 V2        V3  V4
#> 1: 30  0 10.000000   5
#> 2: 10 10  6.666667 Inf
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The `0`'s in the sample, can be located in other columns as well. However, since the amount of columns are limited, I can (as a dirty fix), duplicate your code to apply to `0`'s  in `V2`, `V3`, `V4`. Nevertheless, I would be very interested in a more flexible solution as well.. I will wait a bit with accepting an answer to see if I get a more general solution. If I do not, I will accept this one.

Comment: o which column would you then aggregate? Or would you like to split the value, in this case 20, equally across all other columns?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly: The aggregation should take place in the column for which there is a value in the sample (`V1, row1`). So the value of `V1, row1` should be `30`, whereas the value of `V2, row 1` is irrelevant, because that weight will not be attached to any observation anyway, because there are no observations in the sample to attach it to (because the sample size is zero).